# Does this function on a probability distribution have a name?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology

Let's say we have a discrete probability distribution with sample space $S$ and probability mass function $p: S \to \mathbb{R}$.

We have $\forall_{s \in S}\ p(s) \ge 0$ and $\sum_{s \in S} p(s) = 1$.

I was wondering if, given an arbitrary $s \in S$, we can tell if it was choosen by someone or if it is the outcome of a random process with that probability distribution. Of course we cannot say that for sure, but maybe we can guess how likely it is. I came up with the following formula:

$$
f(s) =
\left(\tfrac12 \sum_{\substack{k \in S \\ p(k)\ <\ p(s)}} p(k)\right) +
\left(\tfrac12 \sum_{\substack{k \in S \\ p(k)\ \le\ p(s)}} p(k) \right)
$$

We have $0 \le f(s) \le 1$. The formula can be applied to continuous probability distributions if we replace $\sum$ by $\int$.

Example:
$$
\begin{align}
S &= \{A, B, C\} \\
p(A) = p(B) &= \tfrac14 \\
p(C) &= \tfrac12 \\
\end{align}
$$
Then we have:
$$
\begin{align}
f(A) = f(B) &= \tfrac14 \\
f(C) &= \tfrac34 \\
\end{align}
$$
One could argue how useful the function $f$ is, but it seems useful to me. I wonder if other people have already used this. So my question:

Is the function $f$ commonly used and does it have a name?

Comment: There are various issues here.  $\sum\limits_{\substack{k \in S \\ p(k)\ \le\ p(s)}} p(k)$ was used (notably by Fisher) as a measure of how likely an observation or a result as or more extreme was, with extreme measured by probability; it is not clear why you would want to reduce the probability of the actual observation.  One objection to this is that *extreme* might better be judged by the value of an observation in the context of the question rather than merely by the probability of the observation.  Another is that you should not look at probabilities of events which did not happen.

Comment: I think I'll call it likelyness then. The context is that I'm thinking of a way to detect if a file is encrypted, [inspired by this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/257362/is-looking-for-plain-text-strings-on-an-encrypted-disk-a-good-test).